# CSRF token или как защитить сайт?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django, csrf

Делаю свой небольшой учебный проект и возник вопрос. Есть код который передает id в views.py:

```
var element = document.getElementById(e);
var json = {};
    var bot_id = element.id
    
    var token = '{{csrf_token}}';
    json["id"]=bot_id
    
            $.ajax({
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
                url: window.location.pathname,
                type: 'PATCH',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                json
                })
            });
```

В панели разработчика выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должен ли пользователь видеть CSRF token?
PS: Я плохо разбираюсь в защите сайтов и понимаю что вопрос обширный. Но как могут еще подменить/взломать/украсть данные? Может есть список частых ошибок которых делать не стоит?

Comment: Клиент может видеть токен (иначе как он его отправит). Суть защиты в том, что получить этот токен можно **только на Вашем сайте**. На фишинговой странице токена не будет, поэтому запрос не пройдёт подтверждение.

Comment: Существует заголовок `X-CSRF-Token`, того что у вас нет. И, да, это нормально что видно этот токен. При входе на сайт пользователю гененируется токен, сохраняется где-то на сервере (в сессии, базе и т.п..) и выдаётся на фронт, где пользователь отправляет его на сервер вместе с запросами, на сервере сравнивается пришедший токен и сохранённый. Самый частый вид "ошибок" это пропуск в запросы к базе вредоносного кода, аля sql-инъекции, чтобы уберечься от этого надо просто обрабатывать входные данные

Comment: @InDevX _"того что у вас нет"_, — у автора же он есть.

Comment: @nomnoms12 после вашего комментария обратил внимание на тег django. тогда вопрос нет к наличию, а так-то я синтаксис имел ввиду